# Checkbox changing Visibility/Display of multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know it's not a BIG problem, but I'm starter in JS and i couldn't find my answer throug some foruns.

**The problem / What I have:**

• 2 Checkboxes (1º Checkbox called "First" - 2º Checkbox called "Second")

• 2 Divs (1º Div called "one" and 2º Div called "two").

• Inside those divs I have label and input tags.

**What i'm searching for:**

When I click on the First checkbox, it needs to disable the Second check and show the div One (hiding the div two). When I uncheck the first, it needs to enable the second check and hide the div one. (Same to second check).

**The HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="first" />First Check
<input type="checkbox" id="second" />Second Check

<div id="one">
   <label>1 Div</label>
   <input type="text" maxlenght="12" />
</div>
<div id="two">
   <label>2 Div</label>
   <input type="text" maxlenght="12" />
</div>
```

**The CSS**:

```
#one{
   display: none;
}

#two{
   display: none;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mfq14ssx/) is the fiddle.

Comment: Why aren't you using radio buttons instead of checkboxes? Also, where's the JavaScript you tried?

Comment: I can use it too. I just need a solution for the JS.

Comment: Side note, you have a typo in `maxlenght`. And could you do what you want with this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mfq14ssx/1/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ymdr5uqd/2/

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
     $(this).siblings('input:checkbox').attr("disabled",$(this).is(":checked"));
     $('div').show();

     if ($(this).is(":checked")) 
        $('div').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();

});
```

Comment: Just the solution i've been searching for. Thanks Erkaner!

Answer (score 0):

Try this for first checkbox:

```
$('#first').change(function() {
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $('#second').attr('disabled', true);
       $('#one').show();
       $('#two').hide();
   } else {
       $('#second').removeAttr('disabled');
       $('#one').hide();
   }
});
```